# Cumulative sum in amortization table python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm creating an amortization table and would like to have a running total of interest paid, but keep getting errors about the value being a float...which it is because interest is never an even dollar amount to be an integer.   I have tried a lot of ways with cumsum, trying shift, iloc, etc. but keep getting errors or not returning expected results.

Here is the code that creates the table...how can I add in a cumulative interest column successfully?

```
`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy_financial as nf
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

interest_rate = 0.36
loan_term = 38/12 #years num of loan rpmt orig / 12
num_payments_per_yr = 12 #rpmt_freq (12, 24, 26)
loan_amt = 7000 #loan_amt
first_payment_date = date(2018, 1, 1) # not needed, changed to be numeric period instead of dates of repayment
adj_interest_rate = interest_rate/num_payments_per_yr
num_periods = loan_term * num_payments_per_yr
co_rate = .2576 / num_periods
llr_rate = .0133       #loan_tb_llr_fct

rng = range(1, int(num_periods)+1)

pmt = round(nf.pmt(adj_interest_rate, num_periods, loan_amt), 2)
pmt

beginning_bal = loan_amt
principal = round(nf.ppmt(pv=loan_amt, rate=adj_interest_rate, nper=num_periods, per=num_periods, fv=0), 2)
interest = nf.ipmt(pv=loan_amt, rate=adj_interest_rate, nper=num_periods, per=num_periods, fv=0)
ending_bal = nf.pv(fv=0, pmt=pmt, rate=adj_interest_rate, nper=0)
records=[]
end_bal = loan_amt
for i in range(1, len(rng)+1):
    bgn_bal = end_bal
    principal = nf.ppmt(pv=loan_amt, rate=adj_interest_rate, nper=num_periods,  per=i, fv=0)
    interest = float(nf.ipmt(pv=loan_amt, rate=adj_interest_rate, nper=num_periods, per=i, fv=0))
    end_bal = nf.pv(fv=0, pmt=pmt, rate=adj_interest_rate, nper=len(rng)-i)
    monthly_co = bgn_bal*co_rate
    npv_rate = 1.2**(i / num_payments_per_yr)
    npvper = -pmt / (npv_rate + co_rate + (.014*(12/num_payments_per_yr))) #20% discount, charge off rate, early payoff rate
    cof = bgn_bal * .0083 #COF basis
    prin_llr = bgn_bal * llr_rate
    int_llr = (-interest * llr_rate)
    net_revenue = (-interest - cof - monthly_co - prin_llr - int_llr)
    records.append((bgn_bal, -pmt, -principal, -interest, end_bal, monthly_co, npvper, npv_rate, cof, prin_llr, int_llr, net_revenue))
    
    columns=['Beginning Balance', 'Payment', 'Principal', 'Interest', 'Ending Balance', 'Monthly Chargeoff', 'NPVPER', 'NPV_Rate', 'COF', 'Prin_LLR', 'Int_LLR', 'Net Revenue']
amort_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, index=rng, columns=columns).round(2)
amort_df`
```

I tried cumsum, shift, iloc, etc.  I tried googling plenty of ways but keep getting float errors or just returning the current month's interest and not summing the prior month.

Comment: What error exactly? Where?

Comment: amort_df['Cumulative_Sum'] = amort_df['Interest'].cumsum()

Answer (score 1):

Try the adding the below line of code:

`amort_df['Cumulative_Sum'] = amort_df['Interest'].cumsum()`

This will add a column that cumulatively sums up the interest column. Not sure why you had errors with cumsum, it should still work with floats.

Example output:

```
Beginning Balance  Payment  Principal  ...  Int_LLR  Net Revenue  Cumulative_Sum
1             7000.00   311.22     101.22  ...     2.79         8.55          210.00
2             6898.89   311.22     104.25  ...     2.75         8.43          416.96
3             6794.63   311.22     107.38  ...     2.71         8.30          620.80
4             6687.25   311.22     110.60  ...     2.67         8.17          821.41
```